# How to abbreviate a middle name in a full name

Tags: javascript

I have code that is trying to take a full name like Marie Carrie Smith or Stan Alan Blan Baker and change it to Marie C. Smith - Stan A. B. Baker. 
I am missing a lot and feel like I could go about doing this a better way but for some reason I am suck and cannot get pass this.

```
module.export = {
    @param {string} name
    @return {string}

    answer: function(name) {
        var splitName = name.split(" ");
        for (i=0; i<splitName.length; i++) {
            if(splitName.length === 3) {
                splitName[1].charAt(1); 
            } else if (splitName.length === 4) {
              splitName[1].charAt(1);
              splitName[2].charAt(1);
            }
        }
        return split.join(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do that a little bit easier

```js
var name1="Marie Carrie Smith";
var name2="Stan Alan Blan Baker";

function answer(name) {
  var splitName = name.split(" ");
  if(splitName.length>=3){
    for (i=1; i<splitName.length-1; i++) {
      splitName[i]=splitName[i].charAt(0)+'.';
    }
  }
  return splitName.join(" ")
}

console.log(answer(name1))
console.log(answer(name2))
```

```
module.export = {
    @param {string} name
    @return {string}

    answer: function(name) {
        var splitName = name.split(" ");
        if(splitName.length>=3){
            for (i=1; i<splitName.length-1; i++) {
                splitName[i]=splitName[i].charAt(0)+'.';
            }
        }
        return splitName.join(" ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just beautify your code a bit:

```
 const [first, ...rest] = name.split(" ");
 const last = rest.pop();

 return [first, ...rest.map(n => n[0] + "."), last].join(" ");
```

Comment: This is great and way more easy on the eyes, how would you add the period after the initials?

Comment: @StacyAreas to add the period after the initials you can amend what is returned at each operation of the map function. Instead of returning the 1st character only (‘n[0]’), you’d suffix it with the period by using string concatenation or template strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little snippet:

```
module.export = {
    @param {string} name
    @return {string}

    answer: function(name) {
        return name.split(" ").map((val, index, arr) => (index !== 0 && index !== arr.length-1) ? val.charAt(0) + '.' : val).join(" "); 
    }
}
```

or if you're supporting **ES6**:

```
answer: name => name
                 .split(" ")
                 .map((val, index, arr) => 
                      (index !== 0 && index !== arr.length-1) ? 
                      val.charAt(0) + '.' : 
                      val)
                 .join(" ")
```